# The position of the adverb "shockingly" changes the meaning

Tags: meaning, adverbs, adverb-placement

a. He **shockingly** used brilliant colors in these paintings.

b. He used brilliant colors in these paintings **shockingly**.

c. Brilliant colors were **shockingly** used.

d. Brilliant colors were used **shockingly**.

e. Brilliant colors have been **shockingly** used in these paintings.

f. Brilliant colors have been used in these paintings **shockingly**.

---

In which of the above sentences

1. the manner in which brilliant colors were used was shocking

and which

2. the fact that brilliant colors were used was surprising, (Shockingly, he used brilliant colors in these paintings.)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that **d)** “Brilliant colors were **used shockingly**.” and **f)** “Brilliant colors have been **used shockingly** in these paintings.” fit the description of 1. In other words, the speaker was struck negatively by the manner in which the brilliant colors were used. Maybe the speaker disapproved of the amount of color used or believed that the juxtaposition of the colors clashed but without further context we don't know.

*[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)* says:

> Adverbs of manner, place and time usually come in end position:
>
> - *He **played brilliantly**.*
>   If the verb has an object, the adverb comes after the object:

```
     [verb]   [object]   [adverb] 
   We made  a decision   quickly  then left.
```

Adverbs often modify an adjective e.g. *The service was **shockingly bad.**; the Netflix movie, “Extremely Wicked, **Shockingly Evil** and Vile“, and “Some foods we imagine are healthy can be **shockingly full of fat**.” Similarly, in a) “He **shockingly** used brilliant colors in these paintings.” and e) “Brilliant colors have been **shockingly** used in these paintings.” appear to fit the description of 2 best.

In sentences **a)** and **e)** *shockingly* is positioned before the main verb, *used*, which expresses the speaker's disapproval that brilliant colors were used.